# Как передать в функцию многомерный массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

[image: "выражение должно иметь тип указателя на объект, но имеет тип 'int'"]

Почему когда работаю с моим двумерным массивом внутри функции я не могу просто указать на элемент массива как в других частях кода? Что я делаю не так? Может я как-то неправильно передаю массив в функцию?

Вот код функции:

```
bool check_cell(int x, int y, bool cells)
{
    if (x < sizeof(cells) && y < sizeof(cells))
    {
        if (cells[x][y])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Подчёркивает "[x]" на пятой строке, пишет: "выражение должно иметь тип указателя на объект, но имеет тип 'int'".

И вот соответственный пример вызова этой функции:

```
check_cell(x, y, cells)
```

Comment: `bool cells` это очевидно не массив

Comment: bool cells[300][300];огорчу но всё же это массив

Comment: `bool cells[300][300]` это массив, а вот `bool cells` это вообще не массив

Comment: То есть его надо как-то в функцию по другому передавать?

Comment: как минимум надо по-другому объявлять функцию

Comment: Просвяти, пожалуйста

Comment: `bool check_cell(int x, int y, bool cells[300][300])` Однако смущает ваша проверка `x < sizeof(cells)` — что вы ею хотите проверить?

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял. А то выражение я потом заменю на более правильную проверку индекса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать std::vector вместо массивов для подобных функций

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool check_cell(int x, int y, const std::vector<std::vector<bool>> &cells)
{
    if (x < cells.size() and y < cells[x].size())
    {
        return cells[x][y];
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> data = {
        {true, false, false, false},
        {false, false, false, false},
        {false, false, false, false},
        {false, false, false, false}};
    std::cout << check_cell(0, 0, data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Функция должна принимать вектор по константной ссылке. Плюс, я бы использовал одномерный вектор, чтобы иметь один сплошной кусок памятию

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашёл. Надо было по другому объявить функцию.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

const std::size_t DIM1 = 300;
const std::size_t DIM2 = 300;

bool cells[DIM1][DIM2];

bool check_cell(int x, int y, bool cells[DIM1][DIM2])
{
    if (x < DIM1 and y < DIM2)
    {
        if (cells[x][y])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << check_cell(0, 0, cells);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Так вы его просто удалите...

Comment: Или оставляйте нормальное объяснение, или закрывайте вопрос. Тут идея в том, что мы создаем базу знаний для будущих читателей.

Comment: Я хотел просто закрыть вопрос, но оказывается их можно закрывать только спустя двое суток.